# Server is getting only null value java

Tags: java, sockets

In the following code the server simply get the text from the client and print it on console..

**I.**
but whenever client send some text the server receives only value as **null**,means on console its **showing "null"**

**II.** how can i use **continuous** data transmission means as **client type** one character the server will **receives** at **same time** and also printing at console..

**Here is server:**

```
try {
        System.out.println("Server Has Started........ \nWaiting for client........"); 
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        client = serverSocket.accept();
        try {
            while (!stop && running) {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                String usercmnd = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(usercmnd+"\n");  
                if (usercmnd != null) {                 
                }break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**here is client:**

```
 send.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        cs = new Socket(SERVERIP,PORT);
                        try{
                            out = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
                            out.writeBytes(text.getText().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception ea) {
                            Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this, ea.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(KeyboardActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve without all the GUI stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this at the server side:

```
    String inputLine;        
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    String fullresponse = response.toString();
```

OR

You can simply do this at the client side:

```
out.writeUTF(text.getText().toString());//to write client data to server
```

and this at the server side:

```
String clientData= in.readUTF();//at server side to read data
```

rather than

```
out.writeBytes(text.getText().toString());
```

Comment: `writeUTF()` works! but how can i do the continuous data streaming using above code?

Comment: use the first part of my answer

Comment: i have tried but its working same as normal.how can i do with it as user type any character at same time same character also print to the console

Comment: Where would you be taking the input, client side or server side? And how are you taking the input, console or GUI?

Comment: now i am trying with console. once it work then i ll move to gui